# Iterating through a folder that's passed in as a paramter to a Bash script

Tags: bash, grep, text-processing

I'm trying to iterate over a folder, running a grep on each file, and putting them into separate files, tagged with a `.res` extension. Here's what I have so far....

```
#!/bin/bash
directory=$(pwd)
searchterms="searchterms.txt"
extension=".end"

usage() {
    echo "usage: fmat [[[-f file ] [-d directory ] [-e ext]] | [-h]]"
    echo "  file - text file containing a return-delimited list of materials"
    echo "  directory - directory to process"
    echo "  ext - file extension of files to process"
    echo ""
}

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -d | --directory )      shift
                                directory=$1
                                ;;
        -f | --file )           shift
                                searchterms=$1
                                ;;
        -e | --extension )      shift
                                extension=$1
                                ;;
        -h | --help )           usage
                                exit
                                ;;
        * )                     usage
                                exit 1
    esac
    shift
done

if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
   echo "Sorry, the directory '$directory' does not exist"
   exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$searchterms" ]; then
   echo "Sorry, the searchterms file '$searchterms' does not exist"
   exit 1
fi

echo "Searching '$directory' ..."
for file in "${directory}/*"; do
    printf "File: %s\n" ${file}
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    printf "%s\n" ${file}
    if [ ${file: -3} == ${extension} ]; then
        printf "%s will be processed\n" ${file}
        #
        # lots of processing here
        #
    fi
done
```

I *know* that it's down to my poor understanding of of globbing... but I can't get the test on the extension to work.

Essentially, I want to be able to specify a source directory, a file with search terms, and an extension to search for.

NOW, I realise there may be quicker ways to do this, e.g.

```
grep -f searchterms.txt *.end > allchanges.end.res
```

but I may have other processing I need to do to the files, and I want to save them into separate files: so bing.end, bong.end, would be grep'ed into bing.end.res, bong.end.res .

Please let me know, just how stupid I'm being ;-)

---

Just for completeness sake, here's the last part, working, thanks to @chepner and @Gordon Davisson :

```
echo "Searching '$directory' ..."
for file in "${directory}"/*; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    # show which files will be processed
    if [[ $file = *.${extension#.} ]]; then
        printf "Processing %s \n" "$file"
        head -n 1 "${file}" > "${file}.res"
        grep -f $searchterms "${file}" >> "${file}.res"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to leave the `*` out of the quotes, so that it isn't treated as a literal `*`:

```
for file in "${directory}"/*; do
```

Unlike most languages, the quotes don't define a string (as everything in `bash` is already a string: it's the only data type). They simply escape each character inside the quotes. `"foo"` is exactly the same as `\f\o\o`, which (because escaping most characters doesn't really have any effect) is the same as `foo`. Quoted or not, all characters not separated by word-splitting characters are part of the same word.

http://shellcheck.net will catch this, although not with the most useful error message. (It will also catch the other parameter expansions that you did not quote but should.)

Comment: Thanks chepner - the loop runs fine now, but the test `[ ${file: -3} == ${extension} ]` is still failing...

Comment: `[[ $file = *.$extension ]]` is a simpler way to check that (and doesn't assume the extension is 3 letters).

Comment: `if [ ${file: -3} = 'end' ]; then` works perfectly, but `if [ ${file: -3} = $extension ]; then` or `if [ ${file: -3} = ${extension} ]; then` both fail to trigger

Comment: Nope, sadly, neither `[[ $file = *.$extension ]]` nor `[[ ${file} = *.${extension} ]]` seem to trigger :-(

Comment: Then you probably have a problem with the value of `$file` or `$extension`.

Comment: D'oh! $extenions is ".end", so the "." is already there... so it's working exactly asyou said. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dycey `[[ $file = *.${extension#.} ]] will work whether or not the `extension` variable starts with ".". The `#.` removes a leading "." from the variable's value (if it's there), so you don't wind up looking for files ending "..end".